# Do we allow character identification questions?

Tags: discussion, scope, identify

I just saw this question asking people to [recognize a character based on some vague description](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82601/character-with-underbite-pointy-jaw-and-bug-eyes). IMHO it's too broad and too much lacking in details anyway, but should we even allow such questions?

And if so, what would be an appropriate tag?

Comment: I would say that particular question is off-topic, but only because it's way too broad.

Answer (score 12):

## NO

Identification questions have an understandably bad reputation here on Movies and TV for a good reason...

It's *incredibly hard* to write a **good** one and *incredibly easy* to write a **bad** one.

At best this is an amalgam of [identify-this-actor](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-actor) (which is usually an image) and an [identify-this-image](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-image) question and the latter of those is *specifically* off-topic.

Vague images and descriptions of a *character* aren't helpful, probably trivia (too!) and almost certainly **waaaay** too broad.

I'd use the last paragraph as my close reason and I see no reason to *create* or use a tag for questions that should, and probably will, be closed and deleted in due course.

Comment: I've never understood why the "Identify this actor" or "Identify this movie" questions get a bad rep here. It seems to me that those sort of questions belong on the Movies SE more than anywhere else. I've seen at least three questions get VTC when they were good, specific questions regarding a character or actor in a movie. It also seems like images are looked down upon, which makes no sense because a picture is worth a thousand words...

Comment: @Omegacron 1. People asking those questions are usually one-offs, and plenty don't even bother to upvote or check the answer. 2. Many ID questions are low quality, some even lacking the ID tag. 3. Pictures cannot be indexed and aren't searchable.

Comment: ...and Image ID's can easily be answered with a simple Google Image Search.